# Strange Problems with Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

Hello to the Experts :)

since the Update from Android Studio I get this strange message and cannot execute one of my projects anymore. Since a few days I tried so many things and want to reach out now for you. Do you have an idea, what could be the error and how to solve it ?

Thank you in advance.

Regards

Martin

---

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @99bc8bc

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, by changing the Version of Android Studio to a previous one. After this it was working absolutly fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create new a project and then do a test run of that project. Then simply put all your code into this new project. It will work because I had the same problem and I solved it this way.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error you just need to enable jetifies in your `gradle.properties` file

```
  android.enableJetifier=true
```